# Excel to find next value with vlookup/index+match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel file that I use to match the two different data and update to my ERP system and I need my formula to check next VLOOKUP/Index+match values.

I am trying to concatenate 3 columns and vlookup a value in another worksheet. However, it is possible to have multiple of same concatenate value as a result, it always gives me the first VLOOKUP value. Due to this, my system won't let me upload it as same results appears multiple times.

This to find in suppliers data, then my data and vlookup to find "shipment number" (concatenate purchase order number and item number then VLOOKUP this to find column 19 "shipment number")

`=CONCATENATE(D2;L2)`

`=CONCATENATE('Update upload'!A2;'Update upload'!J2)`

`=VLOOKUP($E2;'Open PO'!$A:$AO;19;0)`

[image: example data]

Comment: What if you sorted the data and made a small formula to check if the current rows key is the same as the previous rows key?

Comment: I can give it a try, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: just to make sure I understand your requirement, you want to find all duplicate purchase order and item combinations, is that correct?

Comment: I want to find corresponding shipment number from my data(which is unique per line, so one item number can have 3 different shipments) but vlookup will always give the first result. I need it to check next shipment number.